# iPhone: Dynamic spaces in NSString

Tags: iphone

It may be a simple question, but i could't get the answer and needing your help!
I have a string like,

```
NSString *temp = @"Hello How are you?";
```

I have to provide spaces dynamically starting in this string by code. For ex: I need to dynamically add 5 spaces in this string in starting point. So, the output string will be like,

```
@"     Hello how are you?"
```

My doubt is, how can i add spaces dynamically to a existing string? I need it to do this way only, not via any other way like string concatenation etc. due to my requirement.
So, please advise me how can i add spaces dynamically in starting point of the existing string.
Note: The spaces will vary every time, its not constant that i can provide 5 spaces only, it will vary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **NSString** is immutable, so you have to create a new string in any case.

The following code will create a front-padded string with **padLength** spaces:

```
int padLength = 10;
NSString* originalString = @"original";
NSString* leadingSpaces = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:padLength];

NSString* resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", leadingSpaces, originalString];
```